# How to smooth out discrete data-points to look continuous?

Tags: android, smoothing, android-graphview

I have two ArrayLists with `double` data. I am already using moving average smoothing. Data is collected every 200-500ms. This is what a typical graph (using `GraphView` in Android) looks like:

[image: Sample Graph]

Since the data collection rate is limited by the hardware I am using, this is how jagged the result looks. Very easy to see individual points.

How do I make the function look smooth and continuous (either mathematically by altering the ArrayLists or by changing some setting in `GraphView`?

Is polynomial fit the way to go, or should I use a combination of filtering and moving average?

I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to smooth out the functions. Your problem is that you do not have enough data points to make it look smooth since graphview draws a straight line between two data points. I do not think there is a way to draw a curve between two points in GraphView without using custom views. Custom view is another beast so I do not think you want to do that. There are two ways now that you can solve this problem.

First way, if your know beforehand that your data does not contain high noise, then you can perform polynomial interpolation of all the points in your arraylist. From that, you will get a function which you can use to create a new arraylist and calculate the y-values in smaller x-steps than what your data has. This way, you can simulate a curve. But do note that interpolation is costly especially as you go to higher orders of polynomials.

Now, if you know that your data is noisy, interpolation will interpolate (fit) all of the noises and that is not what you want. Then you want to use the least squares method. You can go for any orders of polynomial. Use the one that makes the most sense. Least squares will be less time consuming to compute than interpolation and it has the advantage that if your noises are bias-free (meaning the sum of the noises add up to 0), it might provide you with a better approximation of real values. Also note that in least squares, your computation becomes significantly easier if your x-values in your data are separated from each other uniformly. In your case, this could be true since you mention that you collect data every 200-500ms. If you can poll at a fixed rate, then do it. There are various equations on the internet which provides easy least squares calculations given fixed intervals.